# How to handle touch gestures on TGraphicControl?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

My application is made of TFrame full of TGraphicControls. I would like to enable touch gestures recognition on TFrame but when a touch gesture is started on a TGraphicControl, the TFrame.OnGesture event is never fired.

Is there a way to "forward" a Windows Message to the underlying TWinControl (can be a TPanel, a TFrame...) to make Touch Gestures work when movement is started on a TGraphicControl ?

Comment: `TGraphicControl` does not have an `HWND` of its own, so any touch/gesture message is first received by its parent's `HWND` and then gets delegated to the `TGraphicControl`. Whenever any control gets a gesture message, if the control does not handle it then it bubbles up the `Parent` chain until someone does handle it. Make sure `igoParentPassthrough` is enabled in each control's `Touch.InteractiveGestureOptions` property. I don't see anything that should be blocking the `TFrame.OnGesture` from firing, assuming it is assigned a handler. I don't have a touch-enabled screen to test with, though.